# Insert special characters as text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, typesetting, glyphs

How do I insert the ∝ symbol and other special characters in illustrator text?

I tried and this is what I get instead of the `∝`:

[image]

I searched [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/special-characters.html) about special characters, but is there a way to just paste characters copied from browser rather than going through the glyphs list. After all I don't even know if that symbol exists in the list.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If the symbol is not on the list then you get nothing. If you paste stuff from web to a font that does not have the symbol then you usually get a box. Change the font to whatever font was used on the webpage and then it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're seeing this character `☒`, most likely the typeface you are using does not have that glyph in its character set, or has it assigned to a different unicode number. In which case you need to use a different typeface that actually has the `∝` character or look at the glyphs panel.

Otherwise yes, assuming a typeface has a particular character and mapped appropriately, just copy pasting a glyph from a browser into AI should work.

- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2612/index.htm

Comment: Wondering why even fonts like Myriad Pro, Calibri, Segoe UI not have support for them?

Comment: A 'pro' family is likely to have a ton of characters. https://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/myriad/complete-family-pack click character map then math symbols

Answer (score 6):

Illustrator is not a text editing program and so lacks advanced features. However, the 'Glyphs Panel' is very useful in finding and inserting characters not available directly via the keyboard.

[image: glyphs panel]